# Scrolling speed slow down on sync multiple div scrollTop value

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, vertical-scrolling, synchronized-scrolling

When synchronising multiple independent `div` elements scrolling, there is slowness in the scrolling behaviour. I created a sample below.

I tried a lot of logic measures/code snippets/solutions. but didn't get out of this bug. I need your help in getting its solution.

```js
(function() {
  var getAll = document.querySelectorAll(".divScrollDiv");
  var target = $(".divScrollDiv");
  $(".divScrollDiv").scroll(function() {
    target.prop("scrollTop", this.scrollTop)
  });
})();
```

```css
.divScrollDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<p>Scroll the left div, watch the right one.</p>
<table id="tableFixed" class="divScrollDiv">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td>13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>14</td></tr>
    <tr><td>15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>16</td></tr>
    <tr><td>17</td></tr>
    <tr><td>18</td></tr>
    <tr><td>19</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="tableFixed" class="divScrollDiv ">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td>13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>14</td></tr>
    <tr><td>15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>16</td></tr>
    <tr><td>17</td></tr>
    <tr><td>18</td></tr>
    <tr><td>19</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="tableFixed" class="divScrollDiv">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td>13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>14</td></tr>
    <tr><td>15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>16</td></tr>
    <tr><td>17</td></tr>
    <tr><td>18</td></tr>
    <tr><td>19</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="tableLista" class="divScrollDiv">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="source" class="divScrollDiv" style="overflow: auto;">
  1
  <br>2
  <br>3
  <br>4
  <br>5
  <br>6
  <br>7
  <br>8
  <br>9
  <br>10
  <br>11
  <br>12
  <br>13
  <br>14
  <br>15
  <br>16
  <br>17
  <br>18
  <br>19
  <br>20
</div>
<div id="target" class="divScrollDiv">
  1
  <br>2
  <br>3
  <br>4
  <br>5
  <br>6
  <br>7
  <br>8
  <br>9
  <br>10
  <br>11
  <br>12
  <br>13
  <br>14
  <br>15
  <br>16
  <br>17
  <br>18
  <br>19
  <br>20
</div>
```

Comment: This is not Instagram, please don't hashtag. Also please create a [mcve] in the question itself

Comment: As you're new to SO I have edited the question for you to include the relevant code and remove the unnecessary hashtags. Please follow this format for any future questions you ask. With regard to the issue itself, the problem seems to caused by an overcomplicated UI. Why don't you put the content in a single table and scroll that?

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan ! Actually the scenario is of same kind. I have multiple independent div and have dynamic data from backend, so limitation is that I can't put content in single table.